# small_image -> base_image possible?

Tags: product-view, list-view

i am trying to change a line of coding in my category list views...

> ```
>       <div class="product-image">
>         <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="">
>           <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>" class="small-image" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />             
>         </a>
> ```

I am trying to change the list to appear with small_image to appear with the base and when i use the following i just come up with the default magento image not found placeholder

> ```
> <div class="product-image">
>         <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'image'), null, true) ?>" class="">
>           <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>" class="small-image" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'image'), null, true) ?>" />             
>         </a>
> ```

anyone have any ideas why its not reading the base_image or if i am calling the wrong 'image'

Comment: Have you flushed the cache?

Comment: @lloiacono yep first thing i did :/

Comment: think flat data being on/off would have anything to do with it?

Comment: No, I don't think so. So the output of this:  echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); is the url for the place holder?

Comment: i guess, it is... when i ->init($_product, 'image'); all my images in list view are being views as the magento place holder image

Answer (score -1):

Changing 'image' with 'thumbnail' seemed to work fine.